# Caret Package train() Output Evaluation

Tags: r, model, output, r-caret

I am working through an example in "Machine Learning with R, 2nd Edition" by Brett Lantz. I used the following code to create a model object:

```
set.seed(300)
m = train(default ~ ., data = credit, method = "C5.0")

m
```

The portion of the output I am interested in is:

```
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  model  winnow  trials  Accuracy   Kappa    
  rules  FALSE    1      0.6847204  0.2578421
  rules  FALSE   10      0.7112829  0.3094601
  rules  FALSE   20      0.7221976  0.3260145
  rules   TRUE    1      0.6888432  0.2549192
  rules   TRUE   10      0.7113716  0.3038075
```

The Accuracy SD and Kappa SD are absent from this output. This question has been posted several time, but I have not found a solution. Is the reason because the latest caret package version does not provide this output anymore?

Comment: Hi Dan, if my answer does the trick for you, please mark it as correct, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try m$results.

That will display them all, I believe!

Comment: this worked perfectly! thank you! i cant believe it was that simple